# Send info about the Zap as part of rest hook subscription call

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

In my Zapier App, I am calling the rest hook API hosted on my app's server to pass on the `bundle.targetUrl` webhook URL where the data can be reported and trigger the app.

I want to send more information, as part of this rest hook API call. Things like which action app is used as part of this Zap, what all fields have been mapped in the action app, which of them is required etc.

I want this so that I can configure my app more precisely to decide when exactly to report the data and trigger the Zap.

I think the answer to this question is in the `bundle` variable. But I am not able to find the exact structure of this variable what all data does it hold and if it holds other data about the Zap mentioned above.

For reference this is the current code for subscribeHook function in my app:

```
const subscribeHook = (z, bundle) => {

 const data = {

  url: bundle.targetUrl,

  event: ['new_conversation'],

 };



 // You can build requests and our client will helpfully inject all the variables

 // you need to complete. You can also register middleware to control this.

 const options = {

  url: `${_sharedBaseUrl}/api/v1/convbot/${bundle.inputData.chatbot}/resthook`,

  method: 'POST',

  json: data,

 };



 return z.request(options)

  .then((response) => JSON.parse(response.content));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question.

For user privacy reasons, we don't share data about what apps are connected to yours. So, you won't be able to pass along any other info from the app during subscription.

For future reference, there's info about what's the `bundle` object [in the docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#bundle-object).